# How to use multiple fields to make a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am designing a report in report builder where two parameters are needed, one parameter for the projection and another parameter for a particular budget level .  I can create the first parameter for budget as that is using a specific field, I am looking for a way to build another parameter that allows the user to select a budget level and bring back results for that.  The main issue is these budget levels are their own fields. I have done some searching on here and on google and I cannot find a way of doing this.  I am not looking to create a multivalue parameter as each field has it's own column.

My SSRS knowledge is beginner at this point so forgive me if I was not specific enough.

Thank you in advance for your help/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Edit your question and show some sample data. Also show some parameter values an expected results when those values are chosen. That will help others understand your issue better. I'm sure this won't be difficult but until we know more it's guesswork.

Comment: Thank you, I did get it figured out. I had to build the parameter directly and specify the values I wanted to be available in the available fields box for Label and Value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dataset for budget level and use that in parameter's available value in parameter properties window. Check that below screenshot will get budget seletion.

[image]